# Adding background image to blackberry app not working

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator

i am new to blackberry development and want to add an image to a sample blackberry application. I have tried multiple tutorials, but the image is not displaying in the background

can any one kindly tell me what is the problem?

```java
/**
 * This class extends the UiApplication class, providing a graphical user
 * interface.
 */
public class Diverse extends UiApplication {

    private Bitmap backgroundBitmap;
    private Bitmap fieldBitmap;


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Diverse diverse = new Diverse();
        diverse.enterEventDispatcher();
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new MyApp object
     */
    public Diverse() {
        //The background image.
        backgroundBitmap = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("background.png");

        MainScreen mainScreen = new MainScreen();

        HorizontalFieldManager horizontalFieldManager = new HorizontalFieldManager(HorizontalFieldManager.USE_ALL_WIDTH | HorizontalFieldManager.USE_ALL_HEIGHT){

            //Override the paint method to draw the background image.
            public void paint(Graphics graphics)
            {
                //Draw the background image and then call paint.
                graphics.drawBitmap(0, 0, 240, 240, backgroundBitmap, 0, 0);
                super.paint(graphics);
            }            

        };

        //The LabelField will show up through the transparent image.
        LabelField labelField = new LabelField("This is a label");

        //A bitmap field with a transparent image.
        //The background image will show up through the transparent BitMapField image.
        BitmapField bitmapField = new BitmapField(Bitmap.getBitmapResource("field.png"));

        //Add the manager to the screen.
        mainScreen.add(horizontalFieldManager);

        //Add the fields to the manager.
        horizontalFieldManager.add(labelField);
        horizontalFieldManager.add(bitmapField);

        // Push a screen onto the UI stack for rendering.
        pushScreen(new DiverseScreen());
    }
}
```

and `DiverseScreen` class is

```java
package diverse;

import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.MainScreen;

/**
 * A class extending the MainScreen class, which provides default standard
 * behavior for BlackBerry GUI applications.
 */
public final class DiverseScreen extends MainScreen
{
    /**
     * Creates a new MyScreen object
     */
    public DiverseScreen()
    {        
        // Set the displayed title of the screen       
        setTitle("Diverse");
    }
}
```

Comment: See this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8831430/splash-screen-image-size/8831780#8831780 You will understand better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have set the background image for **one** screen, but you never **displayed** *that* screen.  Then, you displayed a different screen that did **not** have a background image set.

First, it helps to understand the BlackBerry UI framework.  It allows you to create a hierarchy of objects on screen.  At the top level, you have a `Screen` (or subclass of `Screen`), and then inside of the `Screen`, you have `Managers`, and inside them are `Fields`.  But, each level must be added to a container of some kind, and finally, the top-level `Screen` must be displayed with something like [pushScreen()](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/UiApplication.html#pushScreen(net.rim.device.api.ui.Screen)).

[See a little more description on this hierarchy in a recent answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15146740/119114)

In your situation, you should change this line

```
    MainScreen mainScreen = new MainScreen();
```

to

```
    DiverseScreen mainScreen = new DiverseScreen();
```

and then change this line

```
    pushScreen(new DiverseScreen());
```

to

```
    pushScreen(mainScreen);
```

since `mainScreen` is the instance where you added a horizontal field manager that draws your background image.